# QMessageBox with a "Do not show this again" checkbox

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, qmessagebox

How can I show a message box with a "Do not show again" checkbox below?

I imagine something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: [`QErrorMessage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qerrormessage.html) has this feature built in.

Comment: Does my answer work for you? If so feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Qt 5.2 added the possibility to add a `QCheckBox` to a `QMessageBox`. Have a look at [QMessageBox::setCheckbox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#setCheckBox)

Here is some demo code

```
if (this->showMsgBox) {
    QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox("Okay I understand");
    QMessageBox msgbox;
    msgbox.setText("Am I nerve-wrecking?");
    msgbox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Icon::Question);
    msgbox.addButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgbox.addButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgbox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgbox.setCheckBox(cb);

    QObject::connect(cb, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [this](int state){
        if (static_cast<Qt::CheckState>(state) == Qt::CheckState::Checked) {
            this->showMsgBox = false;
        }
    });

    msgbox.exec();
}
```

Comment: This won't work unless `msgbox.exec();` is called after `connect` statement. `exec()` is a blocking call and `stateChanged` signal won't be effective this way. Just tried this with a small demo app.

Comment: Ups  you are right of course. Didn't actually runt he code. Stupid me. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, what is ShowMsgBox exactly?

Comment: Its a boolean member variable of the test class I used.

Comment: On Qt5 getting `error: invalid use of ‘this’ in non-member function` and had to change to `QObject::connect(cb, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [=]( const int &state ){` - a C++11 lambda expression.

Comment: Instead of connecting the signal, it is also possible to check `cb->isChecked()` after `exec()` returns (But the signal works for the non-blocking case as well).