# Python PyQt5 adding a don't show this mesasge again checkbox to QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am struggling to get this working.
I tried to transpose from a c++ post into python with no joy:
[QMessageBox with a "Do not show this again" checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130673/qmessagebox-with-a-do-not-show-this-again-checkbox)

my rough code goes like:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw

...
mb = qtw.QMessageBox
cb = qtw.QCheckBox

# following 3 lines to get over runtime errors
# trying to pass the types it was asking for
# and surely messing up
mb.setCheckBox(mb(), cb())
cb.setText(cb(), "Don't show this message again")
cb.show(cb())
ret = mb.question(self,
                 'Close application',
                 'Do you really want to quit?',
                 mb.Yes | mb.No )
if ret == mb.No:
   return
self.close()
```

the above executes with no errors but the checkbox ain't showing (the message box does).
consider that I am genetically stupid... and slow, very slow.
so please go easy on my learning curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to "port" code, it's important to know the basis of the source language and have a deeper knowledge of the target.

For instance, taking the first lines of your code and the referenced question:

```
QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox("Okay I understand");
```

The line above in C++ means that a new object (cb) of type QCheckBox is being created, and it's assigned the result of `QCheckBox(...)`, which returns an instance of that class. To clarify how objects are declared, here's how a simple integer variable is created:

```
int mynumber = 10
```

This is because C++, like many languages, requires the object *type* for its declaration.

In Python, which is a dynamic typing language, this is not required (but it *is* possible since Python 3.6), but you still need to *create* the instance, and this is achieved by using the parentheses on the class (which results in *calling* it and causes both calling `__new__` and then `__init__`). The first two lines of your code then should be:

```
mb = qtw.QMessageBox()
cb = qtw.QCheckBox()
```

Then, the problem is that you're calling the other methods with new instances of the above classes everytime.

An instance method (such as `setCheckBox`) is implicitly called with the instance as first argument, commonly known as `self`.

```
checkboxInstance = QCheckBox()
checkboxInstance.setText('My checkbox')
# is actually the result of:
QCheckBox.setText(checkboxInstance, 'My checkbox')
```

The last line means, more or less: call the `setText` function of the class QCheckBox, using the instance and the text as its arguments.
In fact, if QCheckBox was an actual python class, `setText()` would look like this:

```
class QCheckBox:
    def setText(self, text):
        self.text = text
```

When you did `cb = qtw.QCheckBox` you only created *another* reference to the class, and everytime you do `cb()` you create a new instance; the same happens for `mb`, since you created another reference to the message box class.

The following line:

```
mb.setCheckBox(mb(), cb())
```

is the same as:

```
QMessageBox.setCheckBox(QMessageBox(), QCheckBox())
```

Since you're creating new instances every time, the result is absolutely nothing: there's no reference to the new instances, and they will get immediately discarded ("garbage collected", aka, deleted) after that line is processed.

This is how the above should actually be done:

```
mb = qtw.QMessageBox()
cb = qtw.QCheckBox()

mb.setCheckBox(cb)
cb.setText("Don't show this message again")
```

Now, there's a fundamental flaw in your code: `question()` is a *static* method (actually, for Python, it's more of a class method). Static and class methods are functions that don't act on an instance, but only on/for a class. Static methods of QMessageBox like `question` or `warning` create a **new instance** of QMessageBox using the provided arguments, so everything you've done before on the instance you created is completely ignored.

These methods are *convenience* functions that allow simple creation of message boxes without the need to write too much code. Since those methods only allow customization based on their arguments (which don't include adding a check box), you obviously cannot use them, and you must code what they do "under the hood" explicitly.

Here is how the final code should look:

```
    # create the dialog with a parent, which will make it *modal*
    mb = qtw.QMessageBox(self)
    mb.setWindowTitle('Close application') 
    mb.setText('Do you really want to quit?') 
    # you can set the text on a checkbox directly from its constructor
    cb = qtw.QCheckBox("Don't show this message again")
    mb.setCheckBox(cb)
    mb.setStandardButtons(mb.Yes | mb.No)
    ret = mb.exec_()
    # call some function that stores the checkbox state
    self.storeCloseWarning(cb.isChecked())
    if ret == mb.No:
        return
    self.close()
```

Comment: bloody hell! cheers mate, I wasn't expecting a full tutorial. You rock! seriously, no irony or pun intended. Thnx for taking the time to explain in details, like to a 10-years-old. That's what I was after but surely not expecting it. Getting the chance to understand stuff under the hood, explained in plain english, and not just copy-pasting is refreshing. Have a fantastic weekend mr music lover.

Comment: and then I just realized you from booty-land too. then: greetings from Genova sir. we'll se the end of the tunnel... at some point.

Comment: @Caligola you're very welcome! Let's hope so... Greetings from Como!